# What is the difference between ruptive and disruptive

Tags: meaning

My brother asked me this question:

> *You can be disruptive, but can you be ruptive? For example, one can be
>   disrespectful and it is also possible to be respectful...*

I thought ruptive would have to mean the opposite of disruptive (because...pattern?). I have looked up the [definition of ruptive](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Ruption) and it seems that both ruptive and disruptive have the same meaning. Why is this so and why is there a distinction if they both mean the same thing?

Upon further investigation eruptive and irruptive are also in the same boat. Again why? Is this a common pattern? Examples?

Comment: That's English for you!  (Not that one person in ten would know what "ruptive" or "irruptive" meant.)

Comment: The downvote surprises me... especially since there is no reason given... :-( This question seems good to me as I would also like to know the answer! :-)

Answer (score 3):

Your premise of equivalence is faulty for both of the word pairs you present. The 1913 Webster's definition for the obsolete term *ruption* that your link points to states "A breaking or bursting open; breach; rupture".

This is not the same as the definition of *disruption*, which Oxforddictionaries.com (ODO) defines as "Disturbance or problems that interrupt an event, activity, or process".

Similarly, ODO defines *eruptive* as "Of, relating to, or formed by volcanic activity," and *irruptive* as an adjective derived from the noun *irrupt*, which means "[To] enter forcibly or suddenly".